# REST API - How should I store a record of an user accessing/viewing a resource?

Tags: rest

Say I have two resources, users and items, for example,

```
api/users
api/items
```

I want to store a record of when an user access an item (which items has access each user). What would be the correct way to do this in a REST way.

I could do something like this

```
POST
api/items/1
{an userId}
```

instead of GET request and retrieve the item and create the view record. Or using a GET request on api/items/1 and then relying on the client to call another api method to add a view record. But those ways just don't feel right.

Is it a recommended way to do something like this in a REST way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious as to why you want an auditing function like storing who viewed the record to be an external REST API call...

I would think the simplest REST API would be to make the access a GET request like `https://{url}/api/items/{id}?token={something_from_authentication_call}` assuming that you've authenticated the user and provided them a token to use with all calls.

Then, since you're internally maintaining a token-to-user association somewhere, have the backend service either write the auditing data directly to a database, or call some other internal service not exposed to the outside world to create the auditing data.

Comment: Mmm, this could work. But I understand that query string parameters are recommended to be used just as filters of resources.

Comment: You can use the query string to pass any state information you need to make the call successful. For GET calls, passing authentication information in the query string is pretty common. You could also add it in the HTTP call header. If you aren't authenticating but you still need a user ID, you could make it a required parameter (i.e. return 4xx or 5xx if the user ID is missing). However, I'd recommend authentication to ensure that you aren't storing random strings for the User ID. I assume you want real users audited for access.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you use authentication before calling your REST? Usually user authenticates before and when the REST is called you know who is calling.
If you don't have authentication you can use any method of passing user as body parameter or as request header.

Comment: I've seen that adding custom request headers is not recommended nor adding a body to a get request.

Comment: You can add query parameter. Are you using authentication?

Comment: I'm not using authentication (at least not yet). So I guess using a query string in the get request is my best option.

Comment: If this is the only REST you need to provide user it doesn't really matter. however if you need to pass user to other RESTs as well I would add custom header with the user name or id. Some kind of simple version of Authorization header. It also will be easier to replace if you add authentication later.